How disadvantageous would symmetrical, four-fingered hands be?
I'm working on a fantasy world in which orcs are more obviously similar to swine and I want them to have hands which look like they could have evolved from pig's feet. My "concept design" is symmetrical and has two thumbs and two fingers, all wider than that of humans and in roughly similar locations to where they'd be on a human hand (if it matters much, the fingertips are "capped" with the vestigial hooves rather than having nails). While I'd expect this to be a significant disadvantage(hand-wave the evolution on this one, it works differently in this setting and they're a created species anyway), how much of a disadvantage would it actually pose? Would tasks like knot-tying, medical work, or weaving be practically beyond them in most cases or just very difficult?

Why would you expect them to have any difficulty? How often do you actually use your little finger for anything?

@1ridgewilliondollars they may have a harder time grabbing things firmly. Additionally they may have problems with doing delicate tasks with their hands as thumbs tend to be less mobile.

@AlexP your little finger is actually very important, your ring finger however is basically useless. the pinky is essential for many grips because it can oppose the force vector of the thumb.

@AlexP i'm not an expert, but it seems to lend itself to hamfistedness to me. They'd probably have better grip strength with two thumbs and no pinky, certainly, but from what i can tell without would probably lack some balance. Could be wrong though

They're more likely to have trouble due to the vestigial hooves than the lack of a fifth digit. The Human ability to manipulate small things depends on finger tips with an enormously dense number of nerves. Replace that with a nerve-dead hoof and that would be a substantial disadvantage.

Most cartoon characters have 4 fingers!

@fraxinus a cartoon is not a reflection of reality. You can't just project illogical fiction onto reality.

I have known people born with four fingers and no thumb and they were able to do pretty much anything they wanted. It just meant that sometimes they had to be creative in a world where most people have thumbs.

@Fallenspacerock I rarely use my ring finger for delicate tasks. Those are mostly handled by the first two fingers and the thumb.  Losing any finger would probably weaken the grip, but for an average person in most situations, it probably wouldn't weaken it enough to matter, particularly for a species evolved for four fingers as opposed to losing one. I know more than one person with a missing or partially missing finger and it barely matters.

@TimothyAWiseman the thumb is one of the most important fingers you have on your hand. So i think having four fingers is going to make things more difficult. While the 2 thumbs probably compensate a lot in the grip department other more delicate task would be a little bit more difficult. Though don't get me wrong they would still be able to do everything but with minor difficulties. Also it depends on how the flexibility of their fingers evolved.

Do you mean something like a koala's hand but without the pinky?

@Flater nah this one does have 5 fingers.

you may want to look up a creature called a neosapien from the exosquad cartoon, they have hands like that. and they even show many tools designed ot fit them.

@Fallenspacerock: I'm not sure what it is you're pointing out has five fingers. It's not OP's hand (given that they both call it a four-fingered hand and list the specific fingers - "two thumbs and two fingers"), and while the picture I linked contains a five-fingered koala hand, my comment clearly points out that I'm asking about "a koala's hand but without the pinky". Additionally (though I do see I could've been more explicit about this), my question was asking about the placement of the thumbs, which can be answered even if there's five fingers on the hand in my picture.

@Flater yeah sorry then i understood that wrong though there are probably still a few different between the hand of a coala and the hand in question.

@Flater yeah, but less "spread out". Replace the hoof-parts on a pig's hoof with fingers and the back ones with thumbs (though more to the edges to give them a "palm") and you'll get a better idea of what i mean in terms of arrangement.

@1ridgewilliondollars: Should've been clearer, I was mostly focused on the two thumbs on the same side as opposed to the top answer which has them on opposing sides.

@Flater they are on opposing sides, but that's my bad for not including a visual aid i think

If you mean a hand a bit like this:

then I don't think it would be of any significant disadvantage, so long as the fingers and thumbs had fleshy pads similar to those of human hands and the thumbs are still opposable. Most "fine-work" carried out by humans only uses the thumb and the first two fingers (sewing, tying knots in a fine thread, weilding scissors or a pen etc.). The ring finger and the little finger are usually only used to help with stability in grasping a cylindrical object like a sword or carving knife. Any number of humans have managed quite well in carrying out delicate tasks after losing one or more fingers. And if you now provide your orcs with a second opposable thumb, chances are that they could display even more dexterity than a human.
If you want them to be clumsy-handed then I see two options. Either get rid of the fleshy finger-tips - the vestigal hooves cover the entire end of each finger/thumb. Or reduce the number of joints in each digit from two to three (as in human thumbs and fingers) to one in each digit.

much of our hands grip comes from the thumb. So just try to grab anything without using it and you find that you can hold the object a lot less secure. So not having a thumb is a problem though their hands may have evolved to compensate for it.

@Fallenspacerock My understanding from the original post was that the orcs had two thumbs, not no thumbs. So long as they are opposable, grasping shouldn't be an issue.

still they lack a 5 finger that could function as thumb causing similar problems.

@Fallenspacerock how could a pinky possibly function as a second thumb better than a literal second thumb?

when i said the the vestigal hooves "cap" the digits, that is what I meant. How drastic do you think the difference would be?

@1ridgewilliondollars they hoves are just nails in this scenario so i think we can ignore them. As as you described the hand is structured like the human hand but without a thumb. This makes it harder to do delicate things or have a good grip on objects. Though they would probably be fine holding most things due to their two thumbs.

@Fallenspacerock the question (that hasn't been edited) states "has two thumbs and two fingers", where are you getting "hand without a thumb" from?

@Sam Dean essentially as far as i know the four fingers are arranged like that of a humble excluding the thumb. So a 5th finger that could make the grip more stable is missing. This finger is the equivalent of a thumb on a human.

Based on the question and what pig's feet look like, I was thinking more of a \// instead of a ||/ meaning the two thumbs were on the same side (i.e. the thumbs are the \ ).

Actually, a good example of what I meant is a koala hand but without the pinky.

@Fallenspacerock I think you are confusing Penguinos bad drawing skills for what is being described... Yes the drawing looks like a hand with 4 fingers and no thumb. but the description is a hand with a thumb, 2 fingers, and then another thumb... So the hand in question is not a 4 fingered hand... but rather a 2 fingered hand with 2 thumbs.

@Fallenspacerock TLDR: Ignore the drawing... the hand being described has 2 thumbs. One on each side of the hand, and only 2 fingers.

@Questor if we see it that way this may fix a few issues. Though delicate work and the grip would be a little bit worse but i think the rest should be fine.

@Questor it is a pretty crappy drawing of  a hand, I admit - drawing on a tiny scroll-pad isn't easy. But I can't see how it "looks like a hand with 4 fingers and no thumb". The thumbs are the digits (one on each side) sticking out at right angles from the centre pair. I can't comment on your anatomy but, on my hands, fingers just don't do that without a whole lot of painful joint dislocation.

@Penguino 1) I thought your answer was good. Comment was aimed to get Fallenspacerock to stop obsessing over your drawing and pay attention to the words that you wrote. 2) Artistically... look at your thumb. the thumb doesn't splay out at 90 degrees. Your thumb is a finger that has been rotated until it bends in a different direction then your fingers. If you look at a flat hand. Fingers have knuckle creases in the middle. the thumb has creases on the outer side.. because it bends a different direction.

The Left thumb you drew is good, and looks like a thumb... the right 'thumb' has creases in the middle instead of towards the outer edge... it doesn't look like it will bend like a thumb. It needs to be rotated Counter clockwise by its major axis.

You're fine.
Based on how humans actually grip things, they can do every grip humans can.  If anything, a few grips might actually work better. The diagonal grip will be the only one weaker.  You are preserving the most important aspects of the hand, honestly the ring finger is largely superfluous, while making the important pinky finger stronger and more opposable.
the hooves will cut down on the sensitivety of the fingertips so they may have issues with things like sewing but it depends a lot on how big they are. Pig hooves still have a large fleshy pad on the bottom, it is actually more like a human finger nail with only the top being rigid. So the hard portion should not be that much bigger than fingernails in the middle fingers at least. But the thumbs oare diffrent and the hoof could cover a large portion of the last phalanx of the thumbs. Pig hooves are not like cow hooves in anatomy.




@Mary as far as i am concerned the thumb is very important to stabilize the grip. As they lack a finger in that position gripping things may be more difficult. Though they still have two thumbs so that should help.

@Fallenspcerock I am confused... They lack a thumb but have 2 thumbs? do you mean pinky finger?
